# Determining Terminal lines/cols via PHP CLI

Tags: php, ssh, command-line-interface, stty

I know that it is quite easy to figure out a terminal's size parameters via the `stty -a` command. When using local CLI PHP scripts, there is no problem at all on grabbing that output via `system()` or so.

But I am trying the same thing via a php script started from an ssh command. Sadly, all that `stty` ever returns is:

```
stty: standard input: Invalid argument.
```

The calling code is:

```
exec('stty -a | head -n 1', $query);
echo $query[0];
```

So the question is: If I can output to the terminal and read input from it (e.g. can `fread()` from STDIN and `fwrite()` to STDOUT in PHP, shouldn't `stty` also have valid STDIN and STDOUT?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am trying to avoid using something like ncurses just to get the screen size.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but doing an exec for the terminal size may result in the incorrect size since it'll be the size allowable for the script, not of the terminal executing it.

Comment: Which would result in requesting the size of a terminal which isn't allocated since SSH itself doesn't allocate terminals for directly called commands. Hm.

Comment: You could try exec('tput cols') and exec('tput lines'), which may give some information, again with the above disclaimer.

Comment: Alternatively it would be ncurses by the seems.

Comment: I guess it's ncurses, yep. The other approaches need $TERM to be defined which can not possibly be the case. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ssh -t`:

```
% php ~/src/termtest.php
speed 9600 baud; 39 rows; 127 columns;
% ssh localhost php ~/src/termtest.php
stty: stdin isn't a terminal
% ssh -t localhost php ~/src/termtest.php
speed 9600 baud; 39 rows; 127 columns;Connection to localhost closed.
```

SSH does not pass in a fully functional terminal by default. Shells and ncurses seem to be able to get them somehow, but to launch something that needs one directly from SSH you need to set -t.

For the same reason you can e.g. launch tmux (or screen) by ssh'ing to a server and *then* typing tmux at the prompt or through `ssh -t _server_ tmux` but not through `sh _server_ tmux`.